# For $f(x)=x^n$, show $f'(x)=nx^{n-1}$ for rational number n

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

We have $x \in \Bbb R$ and $n\in\Bbb  Q$. I understand how to prove the statement when $n \in\Bbb R$, but does the condition $n \in\Bbb  Q$ make a difference?

Comment: You're right that if you know it for $n$ in $\mathbb R$ then you know it for $n$ in $\mathbb Q$, but are you sure you know how to prove this for arbitrary $n \in \mathbb R$? Because we usually first learn it for $n \in \mathbb N_{\ge 1}$, and I'm wondering what your proof for $f(x) = x^{\sqrt 2}$ looks like.

Comment: He who  can do the more can do the less.

Comment: The proof may may a difference in assumptions/axioms, and is good to know how to prove under different circumstances.

Comment: It makes the difference because $x^{w+h}=x^wx^h$ probably hasn't been proven fro real numbers $w,h$.  In fact, $x^w$ probably hasn't been defined for real numbers $w$ yet at all.

Comment: If you *do* know how to prove it in $\mathbb R$ then that is good enough to prove in in $\mathbb Q$ because $\mathbb Q\subset \mathbb R$ and if $n\in \mathbb Q$ then $n \in \mathbb R$ and you have proven it.... but I have to ask *have* you actually proven it for $n \in \mathbb R$.  Are you sure you haven't made any assumptions that are invalid if $n$ is irrational.

Comment: Why don't you give us a rough outline of your proof for $n\in \mathbb R$.  Note: claiming $(x +h)^n = x^n + nhx^{n-1} + {n\choose 2}h^2x^{n-2} + ...... + h^n$ *ISN"T* valid unless $n \in \mathbb N$.

Answer (score 2):

We wish to prove:

$$\frac{d}{dx}x^{n} = nx^{n-1}$$

For all $n\in\mathbb{Q}$. We have:

$$\frac{d}{dx}e^{\ln(x^{n})} = nx^{n-1}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}e^{n\ln(x)} = nx^{n-1}$$

Chain rule:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(n\ln x)e^{n\ln(x)} = nx^{n-1}$$

$$\frac{n}{x}(e^{\ln(x)})^{n} = nx^{n-1}$$

$$\frac{n}{x}x^{n} = nx^{n-1}$$

$$nx^{n-1} = nx^{n-1}$$

This is true, and thus the original equation is true as well. $\blacksquare$

This proof requires knowing the derivatives of $e^{x}$ and $\ln(x)$. I believe the reason for $n\in \mathbb{Q}$ is that exponentiation has not been extended to irrational exponents yet.

Comment: I can add on a small proof of the $e^{x}$ and $\ln(x)$ derivatives if you want